# I wolud like to copy sqlite3 db from memory to hard drive. How can I do?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I wolud like to copy sqlite db from memory to hard drive. How can I do?

I try this way:

```
conn_phy = sqlite3.connect("phy.db")
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = conn.cursor()
c_phy = conn.cursor()

for row in c.execute("select * from table"):
    c_phy.execute(' insert into tablephy (column1, column2, column3) values\
     (?,?,?)', row) #phy db column number equal memory column number
    conn_phy.commit()
```

Comment: You can dump it. More here: [how do i dump a single sqlite3 table in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677540/how-do-i-dump-a-single-sqlite3-table-in-python)

Comment: It seems there is a typo, you might mean: `c_phy = conn_phy.cursor()` instead. Have you tried to pass `conn_phy` instead of `conn` to the code that populates `conn`?

Answer (score 4):

`sqlite3` Python module does not expose [`sqlite3_backup_*()` C functions](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html). There is probably no *direct* way to save in-memory database into a database file on disk.

An analog of `old_db.iterdump()` + `new_db.executescript()` could be used (not tested):

```
import sqlite3

old_db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
# here's code that works with old_db
# ...

# dump old database in the new one
with sqlite3.connect('test.db') as new_db:
    new_db.executescript("".join(old_db.iterdump()))
```

Based on [@mouad's answer to the opposite quesiton (loading from file to in-memory db)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4019081/4279).